# Trouble getting SQLite to run under Mono on Linux

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono

I'm a begginer at C#, and I'm having trouble running this SQLite+Dapper demo:
https://github.com/mercury2269/SQLiteDemo

And I'm getting the following error when running:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: System.Data.SQLite.dll
```

The files are available at the same directory and under x86 and x64 folders. I'm running under Linux using Mono.

Have no idea where to look now, so if you guys need any additional info, just ask!

UPDATE:

Had to add the Mono.Data.Sqlite package to the project and change the file Data\SqLiteBaseRepository.cs to the following:

```
using System;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;

namespace SQLiteDemo.Data
{
    public class SqLiteBaseRepository
    {
        public static string DbFile
        {
            get { return Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/SimpleDb.sqlite"; }
        }

        public static SqliteConnection SimpleDbConnection()
        {
            return new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + DbFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use Mono.Data.SQLite instead of System.Data.SQLite

Comment: This fixed it! Put it as an answer so I can give you a thumbs up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're targeting explicitly Mono then use the Mono version of the SQLite connector (never knew why they decided to break the namespace compatibility, but that's how they did it).

Just replace the references and usings from `System.Data.SQLite` to `Mono.Data.SQLite`